# SWT TitleAreaDialog: How to place a Button on the LEFT of ButtonArea?

Tags: java, dialog, swt

I just created a new class that extends **TitleAreaDialog**.

I overrode the method **createButtonsForButtonBar** and I was able to add new buttons. But placing one on the **LEFT**?? (Default is the right, besids OK and CANCEL).

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack... please post some code to make things easier !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, don't override `createButtonsForButtonBar`, that will have already set up the `GridLayout` such that the buttons are on the right side.  Instead, override `createButtonBar`, which will let you have control over the entire composite there.

It's easy to add something to the left side and then let SWT place the OK / Cancel buttons for you - which I recommend, since you would otherwise have to duplicate the logic of where the "default" button gets placed (far-right on Mac OS and recent GNOME, to the left of the Cancel button on Win32 and older GNOME.)  In this case, you can set up a composite that spans the entirety of the button bar and then let SWT draw its button bar in the far right.

For example:

```
@Override
protected Control createButtonBar(final Composite parent)
{
    final Composite buttonBar = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = false;
    layout.horizontalSpacing = convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(IDialogConstants.HORIZONTAL_SPACING);
    buttonBar.setLayout(layout);

    final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BOTTOM, true, false);
    data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    data.grabExcessVerticalSpace = false;
    buttonBar.setLayoutData(data);

    buttonBar.setFont(parent.getFont());

    // place a button on the left
    final Button leftButton = new Button(buttonBar, SWT.PUSH);
    leftButton.setText("Left!");

    final GridData leftButtonData = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, true);
    leftButtonData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    leftButtonData.horizontalIndent = convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(IDialogConstants.HORIZONTAL_MARGIN);
    leftButton.setLayoutData(leftButtonData);

    // add the dialog's button bar to the right
    final Control buttonControl = super.createButtonBar(buttonBar);
    buttonControl.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    return buttonBar;
}
```

Comment: It is the right solution!! Thanks!!

I already tried something similar but I was jocked by the WindowBuilder, that doesn't show the correct solution in its Debug Mode (neither your solution, but in the real execution it goes correctly!)

Thanks a lot!!